# Table constructed using div tag instad of <tr> and <td> tag

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver

In my selenium project, I have a web table which is constructed using only `div` tag instead of `<td>` and `<tr>` tag. In this case, how can I find the number of rows in such a table.

Comment: HTML and Code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Can you provide a sample table structure,just how your html looks like. Looks like you are using angular 2 controls .That's where the control looks like a table but if you scan it,its all nested div tags. I have dealt with this issue before I just need your HTML structure so that I can post the solution.
If your table structure is something like this

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>



 public void IterateThroughDivTable(IWebElement tblParentObj)
        {
            var childCount = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)DriverContext.Driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childNodes.length; ", tblParentObj);
            for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(childCount); i++)
            {
                var rowDivTag = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)DriverContext.Driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childNodes["+i+"].tagName; ", tblParentObj);

                //check to see if its a div tag else ignore it
                if (rowDivTag.ToString() == "div")//this is your row
                {
                    var tr = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)DriverContext.Driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[" + i + "]; ", tblParentObj);
                    //now try to find the nested div tag inside each tr div tag
                    foreach (IWebElement tc in (IEnumerable)tr)
                    {
                        var colDivTag = ((IJavaScriptExecutor)DriverContext.Driver).ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[" + i + "].tagName; ", tc);
                        //check to see if its a div tag else ignore it
                        if (colDivTag.ToString() == "div")//this is your column in each row
                        {
                            //now this is each cell in the table
                            var divText =  tc.Text;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```